# Why does my image have a gap above and below it?

Tags: html, css, web

I don't understand why the background image of my h1 has a gap at its top and bottom. I've searched around and can't someone else with a similar issue. I've tried a bunch of different properties, but it doesn't change. I have a feeling it has something to do with it being inside an h1, but that's all I got. Any help is appreciated;I'm a beginner.

Here's my code

```
 <h1>K&C Transmission</h1>
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#services">Services</a>
  <a href="Javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>

.topnav {
  background-color: darkblue;
  overflow:hidden;
  border:6px solid black;
  margin-top:0px;
}
.topnav a {
  float:left;
  color:yellow;
  text-align:center;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size:17px;
}
h1 {
  text-align:inherit;
  background-image: url("https://s9.postimg.org/tdjelhj1r/IMG_0090.jpg");
  height:280px;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  background-position:center;
  background-size:cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  font-size:50px;
  position:relative;
  top:0px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
  vertical-align: top;


}
```

And here's the jsfiddle:

[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/Kenneth1026/1z1r1r0m/1/)

--Again, the problem does not exist on jsfiddle. I don't know why it does on Atom.

Comment: did you try altering height of H1? please provide us with some of your code in jsfiddle. it would be better to help you then.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide enough code to replicate the problem **in the question itself**. Better still provide a [MCVE]. Images of code are also not great. It is very hard to copy and paste code from an image.

Comment: maybe the image has the gap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
 * {
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 h1 {
  margin : 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
```

Comment: Still, no change:/

Answer (score 0):

We would need the css applied to your site to get the exact answer, but have you set the following options in your css

```
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Does the link I added I added help? I added that, and it is still the same.

Comment: Also, I tried this on jsfiddle, and the gap is not there. It's quite frustrating. It can't actually be a problem with my editor(Atom), can it?

Comment: Have you tried a cache refresh of the page once its up (ctrl +f5) it may have cached your previous css and needs a little kick to update it

Comment: Just tried. I closed Atom and opened it again, the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should just be an image in the   tag. The image will display at the top of the page.

Also, no point in displaying H1/Title again over the image, since the picture is descriptive enough.

Definitely give yourself a credit for using a good quality image, since you're a beginner.

Answer (score -1):

```
<h1>K&C Transmission</h1>
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#services">Services</a>
  <a href="Javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>

<style>
.topnav {
  background-color: darkblue;
  overflow:hidden;
  border:6px solid black;
  margin-top:0px;
}
.topnav a {
  float:left;
  color:yellow;
  text-align:center;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size:17px;
}
h1 {
  text-align:inherit;
  background-image: url("/Volumes/BEAR/KandC Transmission/Media/IMG_0090.jpg");
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  background-position:center;
  background-size:cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  font-size:50px;
  position:relative;
  top:0px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
  vertical-align: top;


}
</style>
```

Try this code,it will work.I removed `height` from `h1` tag.